# Flutter/Dart - Format double to String with thousand separators AND digits after decimal point

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, number-formatting, numberformatter

I am trying to achieve a formatted String from a double variable, which will include thousand separators (",") AND will include always 2 digits after the decimal point (even if it's zero).

I've succeeded to achieve both of them separately, but couldn't achieve them combined together.

Example for what I'm looking to achieve:

```
100 => "100.00"
100.5 => "100.50"
1000 = "1,000.00"
1000.5 = > "1,000.50"
1000000 => "1,000,000.00"
1000000.53 => 1,000,000.53
etc...
```

I've tried to achieve this using:

```
NumberFormat.decimalPattern('en').format(
    double.parse(
        myDoubleVar.toStringAsFixed(2),
    ),
);
```

But it doesn't give my the decimal points if they are zero.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: @F.S07 can you try with my answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this

```
double amount = 1000000;
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US");

print('${(numberFormat.format(amount))}');
```

output:
1,000,000.00

Comment: -wrong comment-

Comment: it rounds double to int which is not usable for crypto price

Answer (score 2):

Here I have used like this.

```
void main() {
  
  num balance = 120000;
    print("\$${balance.toStringAsFixed(2).replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), (Match m) => "${m[1]},") }");
}
```